# snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio

I installed for the first time Ubuntu on my Thinkpad xCarbon x1 2019 a month ago.

Since I installed, I am facing random crashes of Ubuntu, and after a lot of time watching the log cause I found the same pattern over and over before the crash =>

> Oct  8 17:31:23 The-Arch pulseaudio[1969]: snd_pcm_avail() returned a value that is exceptionally large: 6311616 bytes (32873 ms).

This seems to happen before all the crash, it looks like is due to audio, and indeed, every time it crash I am either on a Hangout call, watching a video or listening to music.

It is really painful, and I tried to find fix online, but most of the Bugzilla ticket appear to be unsolved or very old.

- https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201437
- https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=497636
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1274115

I would like to know if some experienced user might know a way to not face this problem anymore.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu, as you said this is an advanced development bug, its reports are spread over the whole audio stack PulseAudio-ALSA-Kernel-Driver. It could be even a hardware specific. Ask Ubuntu may be not the perfect place to find such experts. Try alsa-user mailing list at alsa-project.org for question and their bug trucker triage old bug reports (add more debugging logs) or submit new one as the team guide you.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, possibly related to my focusrite scarlett 2i2 USB device. I'll try to link to further resources if I come to a solution.

Comment: @CalebJay Welcome, this will more useful if it is submit as bug report and attach all audio debug logs like output of `alsa-info.sh`. Probably they ask you also to test last development release with last main line kernel (just live boot from USB if possible). Flagged this for closing. May opened later for update.